# How to record game in cocos2d iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, video-recording

I am  developing a cocos2d app.

It's almost completed but now I want to record the activities of my app as a video file, including sound produced by the app.

How can I implement this?
Anybody can help me.
Please suggest a way to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't new, but since it isn't answered I thought I'd pitch in:

We provide an SDK called "Everyplay" that allows you to do exactly what you're looking for. It's free to use, and is lightweight.

We provide out-of-the-box integrations for Unity3D, cocos2d (1.x, 2.x), cocos2d-x, and you can of course integrate to a custom OpenGL-based game engine.

The documentation is available at https://developers.everyplay.com/doc

The documentation contains an example app key to use when developing, but you can of course sign up for your own client key at https://developers.everyplay.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are many options - and the fact that your app is cocos2d doesn't matter much.

iSimulate works well.  You can actually play the app on your device and record the gameplay as well as the touch events.  This is important if you want to show user interaction in your app.  You run the app in the simulator but you control it from your device.

If you just want to record the app interaction without caring about showing users the touch events, you can use Screenflow or Jing or some other recording software.  I used to use Jing (free) but Screenflow works better for me and it also lets you create more advanced video like a trailer with effects.  *edit* You should be able to capture touch events through the simulator with Screenflow too.  You can choose to show them or not. And can use different indicators for those events.

Search on google for mac or iphone recording software.  There are many options.  I had the best experience with Screenflow because I wanted to make a trailer and gameplay video.

Comment: I know about jing and some other recording apps,Actually my need is to record the video from my app. Like in talking tom app. How can I record my app with my own app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing similar application which allow user record the activity within cocos2d-x activity.
I'm using screen capture method and then combine it using FFMPEG. The performance wasn't too good thought but is the easiest way to achieve.